# Audit failed by marking as duplicate

Tags: discussion, review-audits

I recently failed a review audit; I marked the following question:

[Runtime issues with iOS 10/XCode 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39491675/runtime-issues-with-ios-10-xcode-8)

as a duplicate of

[Hide strange unwanted Xcode 8 logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800790/hide-strange-unwanted-xcode-8-logs)

They both look the same to me; the second one is much older and the accepted answer is identical; there are plenty of good answers in the older one, too.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Is there a chance to lift the ban?

Comment: To me it seems reasonable to vote to close that as a duplicate, with some luck a mod will pass and make a decision whether to lift ban or not.

Comment: Flag one of your posts for moderator intervention and explain the situation.

Comment: I've lifted your ban; this is a known deficiency of triage audits.

Comment: @Shog9 thanks! I'll keep that in mind